# Is it okey to use my os maximum time from flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, bios

I previously use ubuntu os. But it is very difficult to find something for ubuntu then windows. And my college their use Windows. And as maximum place windows is use and maximum youtube tutorial available for Windows, I change my os to Windows.
  But I love Ubuntu. and for codding ubuntu is much better than windows. So I use ubuntu using flash drive to run ubuntu.

So if I use my laptop most of the time from flash drive is it harmful for my laptop ?

Comment: Actually this is not my question

Comment: I want to know if I run os from flash drive then will it harmful for my laptop system or Hardware etc.

Comment: And Yes I use os from flash drive most of the time. Is it harmful ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Ubuntu from a flash drive is not harmful to your computer's hardware except for the flash drive itself which is not designed ruggedly enough to take the large number of read/writes that running an operating system requires, and it will eventually wear out. I don't consider this to be much of an economic issue because USB flash drives are so inexpensive, as long as whatever data is stored on the flash drive is backed up.

Also the performance of running Ubuntu in this way is less than would be desired. Running Ubuntu from a portable external SSD has better performance than you get from a flash drives. It's smoother, more stable and there is less annoying lagging.

Comment: But my performance is right

Comment: Actually I use os from flash drive most of the time. Is it harmful ?

Comment: The only thing you have to worry about that is harmful is that it will wear out the USB flash drive itself, but USB flash drives are so cheap that I consider them to be a disposable item anyway.,

Comment: Ok my usb should damage but laptop will have no problem . Right ?

Comment: Your laptop will not be damaged by running Ubuntu from a USB flash drive.

Comment: Ok thank you for giving this information

Comment: Keep good backups often, not on flash drive.  No harm to your laptop, unless you remove and plug in flash drive very often. A few times a day.  Keep flash drive plugged in usb port as long as possible.  Damaged to usb port is possible if plugging in very often or being knock around when moving laptop with flash drive in.